# Determinate if a form submitted, inside a component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a template-driven form, with a custom component inside what should handle a normal text input, and display error messages.

```
<form name="loginForm" #loginForm="ngForm">
```

I know, my form has the name "loginForm". Inside I use my component:

```
<app-input-field2
    #loginPagePassField="ngModel"
    name="password"
    [(ngModel)]="user.password"
    required="true"
    type="password"
    placeholderKey="loginPage.input.password">
</app-input-field2>
```

(ControlValueAccessor implemented if it's matter...)
It has the attribute "required", and inside, I display an error message when the user does not fill this field. But when should I display it? First, when user touched, but did not filled it, so inside a component, there is:

```
<input
    #inputElement="ngModel"
    [(ngModel)]="inputValue"
    ....
<div *ngIf="inputElement.errors && inputElement.touched">
    ((display error))
</div>
```

It's works all fine! But... I should display this error even after the user tried to submit the form, but the field is untouched.
What should I do to get the best, automatic version?
...I can pass through the form's isSubmitted flag to a component, but this should be done in every occurrence.
...Maybe I can assume that the form's template name is always something like "myForm", so I can make query about it, but it's quite ridiculous.
Can I reach the parent form's state somehow  without knowing its template name?

(I should use Angular5)

A simple example: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwenca) -  here, I passed the form, so I could just simply say "form.submitted".  this seems unneccessary to do with every component I have. I want to somehow avoid that.

Comment: Can you share the code of app-input-filed component?

Comment: The user shouldnt be able to submit the form if its not valid. Therefore u should disbale the submitbutton until the form ist valid. Also check in the component if the form is valid. And do this: ```*ngIf="inputElement.errors && (inputElement.touched || inputElement.dirty)"```

Comment: Sure, I can add this logic to the submit button, but disabling the submit is quite unfriendly. How should the user know what he missed? ("Take a * to a required fields" - sure.. but raise an error message in that case should be the best!)

"Also check in the component if the form is valid" <-- that is what I want, but how can I do that? Is the "dirty" flag do this trick? :O

Comment: does the parent form show invalid if the input element in ur component is invalid? Or is this what u wanna do?

Comment: My form knows that it contains invalid fields, yes. It has the loginForm.form.valid property which is false by default (since everything is empty).
I want to tell the component, that I tried to submit my form, and it should now display the error message.

Comment: I would definetly try to use reactive forms. With reactive forms this would be easier. Because u have full control of the form, including validation, change events and its easy accessible in the component.

Comment: I'm new with Angular, not familiar with that yet, but I'll try reactive forms as well, thanks.
I added a very simple example to show what I want: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwenca) - So there, I passed the form, so I could just simply say "form.submitted". But in this example, I passed the form to the component, what is seems unneccessary to do with every component I have. I want to somehow avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my solution after all!

You can inject the parent's form in your component's constructor:

```
myForm:NgForm;

constructor(@Host() parent:NgForm) {
    this.myForm = parent;
}
```

With this, you can make your condition in the component's HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="inputElement.errors && (inputElement.touched || myForm.submitted)">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular form has property:

```
submitted: boolean
```

that returns whether the form submission has been triggered.

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#properties

Comment: Sure. The question is, how can the component knows that information inside the form?